# How to change current working directory inside command_not_found_handle

Tags: bash, shell, sh, bash4

I'm trying to write a not found handle in Bash that does the following:

1. If $1 exists and it's a directory, `cd` into it.
2. If $1 exists inside a user defined directory `$DEV_DIR`, `cd into it.
3. If the previous conditions don't apply, fail.

Right now I have something like this:

```
export DEV_DIR=/Users/federico/programacion/

function command_not_found_handle () {
    if [ -d $1 ]; then          # the dir exists in '.'
        cd $1
    else
        to=$DEV_DIR$1
        if [ -d $to ]; then
            cd $to
            echo `pwd`
        else
            echo "${1}: command not found"
        fi
    fi
}
```

And although it seems to be working (the `echo pwd` command prints the expected dir), the directory in the actual shell does not change.

I was under the impression that since this is a function inside my `.bashrc` the shell wouldn't fork and I could do the `cd` but apparently that's not working. Any tips on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There is most likely a better way to accomplish whatever you have in mind.

Comment: I want to move between subdirs inside the directory where I keep all my projects in an easy way. Doing `cd ~/prog; cd something` gets a bit tiring after some time. I'd love to hear any other suggestions to doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* what's going on is that the shell `fork()`s after setting up any redirections but before looking for commands, so `command_not_found_handle` can't affect the interactive shell process.

Comment: +1 Compare: `f () { echo "$$ $BASHPID"; }; f; command_not_found_handle () { echo "$$ $BASHPID"; }; fooble` (assuming you don't have anything called "fooble"). A new shell is forked. (Also, note that `$SHLVL` and `$BASH_SUBSHELL` don't vary if you include those in the functions for additional comparisons.)

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want to do may partly possible using the `autocd` feature:

```
shopt -s autocd
```

From `man bash`:

> autocd - If set, a command name that is the name of  a  directory
>                         is  executed  as  if it were the argument to the cd com‐
>                         mand.  This option is only used by interactive shells.

Otherwise, just create a function that you invoke by name that performs the actions you are trying to use `command_not_found_handle` for.

Comment: This works perfectly for directories inside `.` but the most important thing I want to get done is being able to move quickly to directories in other locations. I'll keep it in mind though, thanks.

Comment: @FedericoBuiles: What about the suggestion I made in the last sentence?

Comment: That'd require me to type the function name each time I want to swich (which would be effectively the same as setting up `autocd`). I do appreciate your effort though.

Answer (score 0):

It won't change directies if you run this program as a script in your main shell because it creates a sub-shell when it executes.  If you source the script in your current shell then it will have the desired effect.

```
~/wbailey> source command_not_found.sh
```

That said, I think the following would achieve the same result:

```
wesbailey@feynman:~/code_katas> cd xxx 2> /dev/null || cd ..; pwd
/Users/wesbailey
```

just replace the ".." with your env var defined directory and create an alias in your .bashrc file.

Comment: That's not why it's not working. The function is defined in the current shell, but Bash forks a new shell to execute the function (which is not normally the case).

Comment: The idea of defining an alias is exactly what I don't want to do. I have 82 directories inside my `$DEV_DIR` so I don't want to be creating a new alias for each one.

Comment: @FedericoBuiles, he's talking about overriding cd with an alias that also tries to cd to your projects directory, not a separate alias for every entry in it.  You'd maybe want to actually replace cd with a shell function, not an alias, so you could e.g. [ -d "$mydir/$1" ] before trying builtin cd to it.  Also, pwd doesn't take a directory as an argument, so IDK exactly what Wes was going for.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the very same wish and the solution that I've been using for a while was opening a new tab in gnome terminal by issuing the command `gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory="$FOLDER"` from inside the `command_not_found` handle.

But today I've come up with a solution which is not tied to a specific terminal application, but has exactly the intended behaviour.

The solution uses the `PROMPT_COMMAND`, which is run before each prompt. The `PROMPT_COMMAND` is bound to a function responsible for checking for a file related to current shell, and cd'ing into the directory specified in that file.

Then, the `command_not_found_handle` fills in the file when a change in directory is desired. My original `command_not_found_handle` also checkout a git branch if the current directory is a git repository and the name matches an existing branch. But to keep focus on answering the current question, I've stripped that part of code.

The `command_not_found_handle` uses `find` for searching for the directory matching the given name and goes only 2 levels deep in the directory tree, starting from a configured list.

The code to be added to `bash_rc` follows:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=current_shell_cd
CD_FILE="${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/bash-cd/$$.cd"

current_shell_cd() {
    if [ -r "$CD_FILE" ]; then
        local CD_TARGET="$( cat "$CD_FILE" )"
        [ ! -z "$CD_TARGET" ] && cd "$CD_TARGET" 2>/dev/null
        rm "$CD_FILE"
    fi
}

command_not_found_handle () { 
    local COMMAND="$1";
    # List folders which are going to be checked
    local BASE_FOLDER_LIST=(
        "$HOME/Desenvolvimento"
        "/var/www/html"  
        "$HOME/.local/opt/"
    )
    local FOLDER=$(
        find "${BASE_FOLDER_LIST[@]}" \
             -maxdepth 2 -type d \
             -iname "$COMMAND" -print -quit )
    if [ ! -z "$FOLDER" -a -d "$FOLDER" ]
    then
        mkdir -p "$( dirname "$CD_FILE" )"
        echo "$FOLDER" > "$CD_FILE"
    else
        printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2
        return 127
    fi
}
```